# Sql function - NANVL - different behaviour

Tags: sql, oracle

Query1:

```
SQL> select nanvl(to_char(2),0) a from dual;

     A
    ---
     2
```

Query2:

```
SQL> select nanvl(to_char(2),null) a from dual;

     A
   -----
```

**Doubt:**
Why the first query returns 2? I was expecting `0` as in query 2. I am confused . Please explain for me to understand.

Comment: From Oracle Docs: "This function takes as arguments any numeric datatype or any nonnumeric datatype that can be implicitly converted to a numeric datatype. Oracle determines the argument with the highest numeric precedence, implicitly converts the remaining arguments to that datatype, and returns that datatype". Maybe it has something to do with the numeric precedence of null.

Comment: It seems to be a bug: `select nanvl(2d,null), nanvl(2,null) a from dual`.  You should report it to Oracle.

Comment: since nanvl will work only either BINARY_DOUBLE or BINARY_FLOAT hence the first select worked because of implicit datatype conversation [check here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF00214). but i dont know about the second statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
select nanvl(to_char(2),null) a from dual;
```

is equivalent to

```
select nanvl('2'),null) a from dual;
```

The literal value '2' is implicitly type converted into the floating  point value 2, so nanvl() returns
2

try

```
select nanvl('NaN'),0) a from dual;
```

that will give you 0